# Android AltBeacon Unable To Detect PiBeacon Device

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, ibeacon-android, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

I am working on Android beacon app with PiBeacon as a beacon device.
I have setup Respberry Pi As Beacon Device as given on [adfruit website](https://learn.adafruit.com/pibeacon-ibeacon-with-a-raspberry-pi/overview).
I can see that PiBeacon is transmitting by using other BLE Scanner application available on Play Store.
I have download the Altbeacon and configure my Android Studio Project according to given guide on [Altbeacon Sample](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html) but the app is not showing the ble device. Can anyone help me what i am doing wrong ?
Following is the code that i am using for scanning PiBeacon.

```java
public class MonitoringActivity extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer {
    protected static final String TAG = "MonitoringActivity";
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ranging);
        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        // To detect proprietary beacons, you must add a line like below corresponding to your beacon
        // type.  Do a web search for "setBeaconLayout" to get the proper expression.
        // beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
        //        setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
        beaconManager.bind(this);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        beaconManager.unbind(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        beaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
                Log.i(TAG, "I just saw an beacon for the first time!");        
            }

            @Override
            public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
                Log.i(TAG, "I no longer see an beacon");
            }

            @Override
            public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
                Log.i(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: "+state);        
            }
        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId", null, null, null));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The PiBeacon you reference sends and iBeacon transmission, but by default, the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) only detects open-source AltBeacon transmissions.

It's easy to detect other beacon types, but you need to add a new `BeaconParser` for the beacon type you are interested in.  The instructions are right there in the comments of the code you posted:

> To detect proprietary beacons, you must add a line like below corresponding to your beacon type.  Do a web search for "setBeaconLayout" to get the proper expression.

Apologies, for the need to do this -- unfortunately intellectual property restrictions mean that we cannot include the expression in the library or post it on public forums like this.  Fortunately, it is easy to find with a Google search.